# How to access the data from my old hardrive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, sata, partition-recovery, diskpart

My old laptop died on me. After taking out the SATA hard drive and putting it in a SATA enclosure, I am able to access one of the two important partitions that were on that hard drive. The biggest partition (which has most of the data) cannot be mounted however.

My old computer used Windows 7. My laptop is now using Windows 10 (in case that is important). I have tried to fix the problem with diskpart and other tools found online but without any success.

Please see below the print out of the diskpart command:

[image]

As you can see there are two hard drives shown. The first one `*( 0 )` being my current laptop and the second one `*( 1 )` being the hard drive in the USB enclosure. Unfortunately, Windows won't allow me to use the assign command to mount the large Windows partition.

I have read online that this my be a rights issue, but I am the administrator on my machine and diskpart is run with administrative privelidges, so I don't quite understand what I could do differently.

Is there another tool I can use, or another command I have to run prior to `assign` to mount this partition on my old hard drive?

Comment: Can you not sift through the files? It should mount it. Unless the drive is partially dead.

Comment: Could it be that Volume 0, is your boot record?

Comment: Out of the box. A pendrive with linux (search on internet or give it a look [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) ), then  you can start that operative system on the pen drive,  mount the data,  copy what you need and reboot in windows 10 ...

Comment: It does appears you are selecting the wrong disk.  I am taking that error as you trying to basically mount the same volume twice.  Why does DISK 0 report having no free space?  Having mounted thousands of disks from other systems, I have never had any problems, the partitions were simply given drive letters.  If that is not happening there is something else going on or the drive has serious problems ( which means Windows is the last thing you want to use due to the fact better tools exist then diskpart )

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I believe Windows thinks that is the system drive and therefore it won't let you change the letter because of it.

You could try accessing it from Linux (by using SystemRescueCD, for example) and removing the active flag from that partition. Then try mounting it the same way you tried the first time.

If you remove the active flag, you won't be able to boot into your Windows 7 (it's reversible though), but I understand you only need the data. If you're not comfortable with this, let's see if a better idea pops up.